# join similar lines using join command - fail

Tags: shell, join

Why can I not match the following files using the same exact id?

```
$ cat rm2
chr10.101554872.101555148.Charlie4a.Charlie4a_dup2111.hAT.Charlie.DNA.0..

$cat rm3
chr10.101554872.101555148.Charlie4a.Charlie4a_dup2111.hAT-Charlie.DNA.0.. 
 ID1

$ join rm2 rm3 [gives empty output]
```

Comment: Because of `hAT.Charlie` vs `hAT-Charlie`?

Comment: Or what do you consider the "ID"? By default, `join` considers fields to be blank separated.

Comment: @BenjaminW.just noticed that there were some differences between the letters with the symbol `-` as you mentioned. I think that might explain the difference.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?